# ubuntu 12.04 and/or 12.10 can boot from software raid5?

Tags: raid, raid5

I read from a very nice post (http://forevergeeks.com/setup-ubuntu-server-with-raid-5/) that ubuntu cannot boot from a raid 5 partition.

Since the post is quite old I wonder if this is still true or now I can create only raid5 without need to have a boot partition of raid1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried myself with 12.04.1 ubuntu server and... it works!!!

Three disks in software RAID5, no RAID1 needed for boot.